# T-SQL Removing multiple LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, left-join

I have such query. It returns ColA and ColB from TableA and UserName from table Users. Then it displays several fields from TableB as additional columns to results. It works but is there any better way than using these multiple LEFT JOINS ?

```
SELECT a.COlA, a.ColB, u.UserName,
b1.Value,
b2.Value,
b3.Value,
b4.Value,

FROM TableA a JOIN Users u ON a.UserId = u.UserId
    LEFT JOIN TableB b1 ON a.EventId = b1.EventId AND b1.Code = 5
    LEFT JOIN TableB b2 ON a.EventId = b2.EventId AND b2.Code = 15
    LEFT JOIN TableB b3 ON a.EventId = b3.EventId AND b3.Code = 18
    LEFT JOIN TableB b4 ON a.EventId = b4.EventId AND b4.Code = 40

WHERE (a.UserId = 3) ORDER BY u.UserName ASC
```

TableB looks like:

```
Id | EventId | Code | Value
----------------------------
1  |    1    |  5   | textA
2  |    1    |  15  | textB
3  |    1    |  18  | textC
```

Sometimes Code is missing but for each event there are no duplicated Codes (so each LEFT JOIN is just another cell in the same result record).

Comment: Does it work? Is it acceptably fast? If yes-and-yes, why change it?

Comment: What is wrong with multiple left joins? And what do you mean by "better? If your query returns the correct results in an acceptable amount of time then just leave it alone. Otherwise you are spending time on something that has no value.

Comment: It does a look a bit 'hacky', especially if we use a lot of these LEFT JOINs. I was hoping there is some kind of mechanizm that could substitute them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot understand why you want to change something that is working, but here's another way (which does those `LEFT` joins, but in a different way):

```
SELECT a.COlA, a.ColB, u.UserName,
  ( SELECT b.Value FROM TableB b WHERE a.EventId = b.EventId AND b.Code = 5 ),
  ( SELECT b.Value FROM TableB b WHERE a.EventId = b.EventId AND b.Code = 15 ),
  ( SELECT b.Value FROM TableB b WHERE a.EventId = b.EventId AND b.Code = 18 ),
  ( SELECT b.Value FROM TableB b WHERE a.EventId = b.EventId AND b.Code = 40 )

FROM TableA a JOIN Users u ON a.UserId = u.UserId

WHERE (a.UserId = 3) 

ORDER BY u.UserName ASC
```

Comment: maybe all those left joins are slow? I haven't tested but methinks a single left join and some tests could be faster. But I have not thought it though completely.

Comment: If there is a (unique) index on `(EventId, Code `, I don't think any variation would make much difference in speed. But it does depend on data distribution. If for an Event, there are tens or hundreds of Codes, your `GROUP BY` may be slower than the `LEFT JOIN` solution.

Comment: For many users I mean, the `WHERE (a.UserId = 3)` in this case would limit the search in all variations that any difference would be unnoticed.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  a.COlA, a.ColB, u.UserName
  ,MAX(CASE WHEN b.Value = 5 THEN b.value ELSE 0 END) AS V5
  ,MAX(CASE WHEN b.Value = 15 THEN b.value ELSE 0 END) AS V15 
  ,MAX(CASE WHEN b.Value = 18 THEN b.value ELSE 0 END) AS V18 
  ,MAX(CASE WHEN b.Value = 40 THEN b.value ELSE 0 END) AS V45 
  ,COUNT(CASE WHEN b.Value not IN (5,15,18,40) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS CountVOther
FROM TableA a 
INNER JOIN Users u ON a.UserId = u.UserId
LEFT  JOIN TableB b ON (a.EventId = b.EventId)
WHERE (a.UserId = 3) 
GROUP BY a.colA, a.colB, u.Username
ORDER BY u.UserName ASC
```